# "For nothing but (to)..."?

Tags: to-for

```
"You should do this, even if for nothing but to test."
"You should do this, even if for nothing but testing."
```

The first sentence feels acceptable, but is it wrong because of "for"? After all, it would be okay to say "for testing", but not "for to test".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both fine.

*For nothing but* means *only*, so you can't remove *nothing but* without damaging the meaning.  You could say:

*You should do this, even if only to test.*

*You should do this, even if only for testing.*

Comment: That makes sense, now! "For nothing but" is its own phrase.